# GEE Python API method 'prepare_for_export' not available

Tags: python, attributeerror, google-earth-engine

I want to prepocess a batch of Sentinel-2 images using the [code provided by ndminhhus](https://github.com/ndminhhus/geeguide/blob/master/jupyter_notebooks/02.Atm-corr-Sentinel2.ipynb). Earth Engine authentication, Py6S, custom module "atmospheric", basically all necessary modules have been installed and updated. The code seems to connect to functions in [batch.py](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/ee/batch.py). This script uses the GEE Python API method prepare_for_export() (as stated in the [documentation](https://gee-python-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ee.html)).

Upon running my code, I receive the error `AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'prepare_for_export'.`

Relevant snippet in ndminhhus' code:

```
def func1(img):
# Omitted lines 2 - 97
        fname = ee.String(img.get('system:index')).getInfo()
        export = ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset(\
            image=ref,
            description= 'S2_BOA_'+fname,
            assetId = 'users/Bmperezaraujo/Py6S_Harmonisation'+'S2_BOA'+fname,
            region = region,
            scale = 10,
            maxPixels = 1e13)
    
        # uncomment to run the export
        export.start()
        print('exporting ' +fname + '--->done')
    
S2_col = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterBounds(region).filterDate(startDate,endDate).filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',50))
img1 = ee.Image(S2_list.get(9))
toa = img1
boa = ee.Image(func1(toa))
```

Relevant snippet in batch.py:

```
class Export(object):
# Omitted lines 170 - 242
    def toAsset(
        image,
        description='myExportImageTask',
        assetId=None,
        pyramidingPolicy=None,
        dimensions=None,
        region=None,
        scale=None,
        crs=None,
        crsTransform=None,
        maxPixels=None,
        **kwargs):
# Omitted explanatory comments in lines 255 - 291
      config = _capture_parameters(locals(), ['image'])
      config = _prepare_image_export_config(image, config,
                                            Task.ExportDestination.ASSET)
      return _create_export_task(config, Task.Type.EXPORT_IMAGE)

# Omitted lines 296 - 962

def _prepare_image_export_config(image, config, export_destination):
  """Performs all preparation steps for an image export.

  Args:
    image: The Image to be exported.
    config: All the user-specified export parameters. May be modified.
    export_destination: One of the Task.ExportDestination values.

  Returns:
    A config dict containing all information required for the export.
  """
  # Supply some defaults.
  if (export_destination != Task.ExportDestination.ASSET and
      'fileFormat' not in config):
    config['fileFormat'] = 'GeoTIFF'

  _canonicalize_parameters(config, export_destination)

  image, config = image.prepare_for_export(config)
  # Build an ExportImageRequest. Delete values from "config" as we go so we
  # can check at the end for any leftovers. Any computed objects will be
  # serialised in data.py before the request is sent.
  request = {}
  request['expression'] = image
  if 'description' in config:
    request['description'] = config.pop('description')

  if export_destination == Task.ExportDestination.ASSET:
    asset_export_options = {}
    asset_export_options[
        'earthEngineDestination'] = _build_earth_engine_destination(config)
    # This can only be set by internal users.
    if 'tileSize' in config and 'shardSize' in config:
      raise ee_exception.EEException(
          'Both "shardSize" and "tileSize" cannot be set.')
    if 'tileSize' in config:
      asset_export_options['tileSize'] = {
          'value': int(config.pop('tileSize'))}
    # "shardSize" is the old name for "tileSize".
    if 'shardSize' in config:
      asset_export_options['tileSize'] = {'value': int(config.pop('shardSize'))}
    if 'pyramidingPolicy' in config:
      pyramiding_policy = config.pop('pyramidingPolicy')
      if '.default' in pyramiding_policy:
        asset_export_options[
            'pyramidingPolicy'] = pyramiding_policy.pop('.default').upper()
      if pyramiding_policy:
        asset_export_options['pyramidingPolicyOverrides'] = {
            band: policy.upper() for band, policy in pyramiding_policy.items()
        }
    request['assetExportOptions'] = asset_export_options
  else:
    request['fileExportOptions'] = _build_image_file_export_options(
        config, export_destination)

  if 'maxPixels' in config:
    # This field is an Int64Value, so it needs an inner "value" field, and
    # the value itself is a string, not an integer, in the JSON encoding.
    request['maxPixels'] = {'value': str(int(config.pop('maxPixels')))}

  # This can only be set by internal users.
  if 'maxWorkers' in config:
    request['maxWorkers'] = {'value': int(config.pop('maxWorkers'))}

  # Of the remaining fields in ExportImageRequest:
  # - All the values that would go into the PixelGrid should have been folded
  #   into the image's Expression.
  # - The request ID will be populated when the Task is created.
  # We've been deleting config parameters as we handle them. Anything left
  # over is a problem.
  if config:
    raise ee_exception.EEException(
        'Unknown configuration options: {}.'.format(config))

  return request
```

The same snippets are in traceback. Cell is ndminhhus' code, File is batch.py.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 2
      1 toa = img1
----> 2 boa = ee.Image(func1(toa))

Cell In[10], line 99, in func1(img)
     93 # define YOUR assetID 
     94 # in my case it was something like this..
     95 #assetID = 'users/samsammurphy/shared/sentinel2/6S/ESRIN_'+dateString
     96 #assetID = 'users/ndminhhus/eLEAF/nt/s2_SIAC/'+fname,
     97 #export
     98 fname = ee.String(img.get('system:index')).getInfo()
---> 99 export = ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset(\
    100     image=ref,
    101     description= 'S2_BOA_'+fname,
    102     assetId = 'users/Bmperezaraujo/Py6S_Harmonisation'+'S2_BOA'+fname,
    103     region = region,
    104     scale = 10,
    105     maxPixels = 1e13)
    107 # uncomment to run the export
    108 export.start()

File c:\Users\bpere\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ee\batch.py:293, in Export.image.toAsset(image, description, assetId, pyramidingPolicy, dimensions, region, scale, crs, crsTransform, maxPixels, **kwargs)
    255 """Creates a task to export an EE Image to an EE Asset.
    256 
    257 Args:
   (...)
    290   An unstarted Task that exports the image as an Earth Engine asset.
    291 """
    292 config = _capture_parameters(locals(), ['image'])
--> 293 config = _prepare_image_export_config(image, config,
    294                                       Task.ExportDestination.ASSET)
    295 return _create_export_task(config, Task.Type.EXPORT_IMAGE)

File c:\Users\bpere\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ee\batch.py:981, in _prepare_image_export_config(image, config, export_destination)
    977   config['fileFormat'] = 'GeoTIFF'
    979 _canonicalize_parameters(config, export_destination)
--> 981 image, config = image.prepare_for_export(config)
    982 # Build an ExportImageRequest. Delete values from "config" as we go so we
    983 # can check at the end for any leftovers. Any computed objects will be
    984 # serialised in data.py before the request is sent.
    985 request = {}

AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'prepare_for_export'
```

I have double-checked that my input img is of ee.image.Image type.

I have a functioning GEE Python API.

I checked whether batch has the prepare_for_export method with `hasattr(ee.batch, 'prepare_for_export')`, but it returned me a negative.

How can I import the missing GEE Python API method?

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.  I don't see where this ```prepare_for_export``` comes from.

Comment: @ewokx included traceback.

Comment: You've removed your code.

Comment: @ewokx I did it because the traceback showed the same snippets. I just added them again, hopefully with more context.